# Accessing functions from external files in class definition

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to access functions from another file for use inside my class definition:

```
// math.cpp
int Sum(int a, int b){
  return (a + b);
}

// my_class.cpp
#include <math.cpp>
#include <my_class.h>

int ComputeSomething() {
  ...

  return ::Sum(num1, num2);
}
```

Despite my best efforts, I can't get the compiler to spit out anything outside the likes of `::Sum has not been declared` or `Sum was not declared in this scope.`

I'm trying to wrap my head around code organization in C++, any help appreciated.

It might be worth noting that I'm programming for Arduino.

Comment: Are you showing us all of the relevant code in `math.cpp` ? No namespaces at all ?

Comment: You are including the entire ".cpp file. That, although it may work initially, isn't a good idea. Do you have a "math.h" file, too, that includes declarations (but not definitions) of functions? That's the one you should include. And best don't name the files "math.h/.cpp", but something more specific to your project. It might get confused with the built-in math library.

Comment: @jogojapan Thanks, those names are only for keeping this question readable. I tried implementing this with a *.h file but it didn't help with the problem at hand

Comment: @J.N. No namespaces at all, although I did try wrapping the contents of `math.cpp` in a namespace to no avail

Comment: Furthermore, there are two ways of using `#include`: `#include <...>` and `#include "..."`. For the former, you need to be sure the library is on the include path. For a start, best use the `"..."` syntax, with a path relative to the directory you are building from.

Comment: @jogojapan Will the compiler not warn me if it can't find the file I'd like to include with `#include <...>` ?

Comment: @Acco, then please show us a full source that can reproduce the problem and how you compile it. Try removing the "::", we never know.

Comment: It appears the `#include "..."` did the trick, though I'm surprised my compiler did not warn me it was unable to find the library. @jogojapan please post an answer so that I may accept it.

Comment: @Acco (about the warning when using `<...>`) Yes, it should warn you. But if you are actually using .h (not .cpp), it might indeed find a built-in math library and include it, but that won't define the your `Sum` function obviously. Not sure if that's really the problem, but best exclude the possibility.

Comment: FWIW, my header file was named "AccoMath.h" as not to be confused with any built-in libraries. Yet the Arduino compile method did not load nor warn when I called `#include <AccoMath.h>`. Irregardless, this issue is resolved.

Comment: @Acco Hmm. I don't really know why there was no warning. Perhaps somebody else who knows Arduino better can explain that. Best don't accept my answer just yet.

Comment: Are num1 and num2 of type int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to access functions from a user-defined library, best divide that library into a .h (or .hpp) and a .cpp file. I understand you have actually done this, but tried various options – among them the inclusion of the .cpp file – for the sake of finding a solution.

Still, to ensure things work as expected, the declarations of functions and classes should go into the .h file, best protected by something like

```
#ifndef MY_H_FILE
#define MY_H_FILE

/* ..Declarations.. */

#endif
```

Then to include the .h file (I'll assume it's named *my.h*), either use

```
#include "my.h"    // path relative to build directory
```

or

```
#include <my.h>    // path relative to any of the include paths
```

The latter only works if *my.h* is found on an **include path** previously known to the compiler (e.g. what is specified using the `-I` command line option in GCC). The former works if the path to the .h file given is **relative to the directory** your are building from.

Finally, do not use a file name that can be confused with a system library (such as "math.h"), especially if you are using the `<...>` syntax, as the include path will definitely include the system library header files.

Comment: From the comments to the question I understand there are some specific Arduino issues which caused the compiler not to issue a warning, although it couldn't have found the header file specified by OP. My answer doesn't really give an explanation for that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the instructions given [here](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/Libraries)?

> User-created libraries as of version 0017 go in a subdirectory of your
>   default sketch directory. For example, on OSX, the new directory would
>   be ~/Documents/Arduino/libraries/. On Windows, it would be My
>   Documents\Arduino\libraries. To add your own library, create a new
>   directory in the libraries directory with the name of your library.
>   The folder should contain a C or C++ file with your code and a header
>   file with your function and variable declarations. It will then appear
>   in the Sketch | Import Library menu in the Arduino IDE.

Comment: Yes, I had thanks. Issue resolved by using `#include "../relative/path"` as opposed to `#include <FileName.h>`